# How to set a a unique id to the elements of a DOM in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

To add more context, I would like to incorporate [Product Fruits](https://productfruits.com/product/tours) to our ember app. The service that we will use is the `Tours` of Product Fruits. When creating a tour, product fruits target the element of client app with using id of an element. Ember generates ID for every element of the DOM. For example, if you have a button, the ID can be `id="priority-navbar-item-ember110"`. However, if you refresh the page, the ID changes.

Question: Besides using data-test selectors, how can I have a unique id and will not change after refreshing the page or revisiting the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to point to a good solution without extra information… I guess you are talking about [this product](https://productfruits.com/product/tours)?

I have a couple of ideas, although they might not be relevant without more data:

- Create a dynamic ID based on some unique property of what you are tracking;
- Set hardcoded IDs for this tour (I’d probably go with this one).

Comment: Hey @gnclmorais, you are right. It's the Product Fruits with the link you've posted. Your approach is good, However, it's still quiet the same as setting a data-test selector for each element I will target.